# How to create datagrid with mixed content of its columns?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have class `Calc` for some calculation, input parameters are:

- `int a`
- `int b`
- `bool c`

Output parameters:

- `int d = a + b`
- `double e = (a * a) / (b * b)`
- `bool f = !c`

I created `ObservableCollection`, that contains input and output data for two calcs. I need to create table with the following content:

```
===================================
| Parameter | Calc 1   | Calc   2 |
===================================
| a         | [     1] | [     5] |
| b         | [     2] | [    10] |
| c         | [x]      | [ ]      |
| d         | 3        | 15       |
| e         | 0.25     | 0.25     |
| f         | false    | true     |
===================================
```

First column contains names of parameters, second, third — input and output parameters for every calc. First two rows should contain inputs in order user could type new values of input data for calculation. Third row should contain checkboxes.

Is it possible to realize such dynamic table in WPF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/apply-conditional-data-template-in-data-grid/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my best to construct what you ask for. When rotating the DataGrid it has the side-effect that the order of the datagrid items are in reverse. That is why the datagrid columns have been reversed in the XAML, and you will notice it through the tab-order. But please try the following code and xaml.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace HorizontalDataGridMixedContentFromCalc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Calculation> calculations = new ObservableCollection<Calculation>();
        public ObservableCollection<Calculation> Calculations
        {
            get { return calculations; }
            set { calculations = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Calculations.Add(new Calculation { a = 3, b = 6, c = true });
            Calculations.Add(new Calculation { a = 3, b = 9, c = false });
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public class Calculation : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private int _a;
            public int a
            {
                get
                {
                    return _a;
                }
                set
                {
                    _a = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("d");
                    OnPropertyChanged("e");
                }
            }

            private int _b;
            public int b
            {
                get { return _b; }
                set
                {
                    _b = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("d");
                    OnPropertyChanged("e");
                }
            }

            private bool _c;
            public bool c
            {
                get { return _c; }
                set
                {
                    _c = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("f");
                }
            }

            public int d
            {
                get
                {
                    return a + b;
                }
            }

            public double e
            {
                get
                {
                    if (b == 0) return 0;
                    return (double)(a * a) / (b * b);
                }
            }

            public bool f
            {
                get
                {
                    return !c;
                }

            }

            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HorizontalDataGridMixedContentFromCalc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HorizontalDataGridMixedContentFromCalc"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="DataGridTest" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Calculations, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="f" Binding="{Binding f}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="e" Binding="{Binding e}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="d" Binding="{Binding d}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="c" Binding="{Binding c}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="b" Binding="{Binding b}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="a" Binding="{Binding a}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The result looks like the following, and when you change the a,b,c inputs, the outputs are updated:

[image]